# linq, calculating the count of counts

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out if I have a list of objects that have their own list of objects, how to get the total count.  For example:

```
public class FileWrapper {
   List<File> Files
}

public class File {
   ...
}
```

So with a List wrappers, how do I get the total count of files.

```
wrappers.ForEach(f => f.Files.Count).Count()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to `Sum` the counts of each list, not `Count` the counts of each list:

```
var sum = wrappers.Sum(file => file.Files.Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wrappers.Select(f => f.Files.Count).Sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `SelectMany`.

```
var sum = wrappers.SelectMany(wrapper => wrapper.Files).Count();
```

I do not have access to VS. So it is eyes-compiled.

Like @Servy says, it is a bad idea :

> This forces every single inner list to be iterated to determine its
>   count, when they're capable of just returning the already-known Count.

Comment: This forces every single inner list to be iterated to determine its count, when they're capable of just returning the already-known Count.

Comment: You are right, I leave my answer here for informational purposes.